# How to control number of processes and threads in OpenVINO

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocess, openvino

I want to know how to control the number of processes and threads in OpenVINO.
I executed following command referring to [document](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/model_server/blob/main/docs/performance_tuning.md).

```
docker run --name [my_server_name] --network [my_network] -d -u $(id -u):$(id -g)  -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 \
[my_repository_name] --model_path /models/model1 --model_name models --port 9000 --rest_port 8000 \
--plugin_config '{"CPU_THROUGHPUT_STREAMS": "2","CPU_BIND_THREAD": "NUMA","CPU_THREADS_NUM": "3"}' --shape "(1,3,704,576)"
```

Although I specified the '--plugin_config' no parameters are adopted and 1 process and 80 threads show up in the result of 'ps -efL' command.

Does anyone know the cause of this result?

Comment: Don't run docker image in background (detached mode) to verify whether the server is running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Do not run Docker image in detached mode to make sure the server is running successfully.

If the server runs successfully, the parameters are adopted and shown in the serving info.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I confirmed the value of 'CPU_THROUGHPUT_STREAMS' is correctly set in serving info.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin config parameters can define the number of threads used by the inference engine. Those are the threads dedicated to the inference execution. OpenVINO™ Model Server process will use more threads because some of them are related to gRPC and REST API servers.

They will use the number of threads dependent on the number of available CPU cores and for the number of REST server threads. They can be tuned with the parameter --rest_workers.

gRPC threads are not configurable now. They are set to the number of cpu cores, but it is possible to pass --grpc_channel_arguments to tune grpc server behavior.